# doxygen generate doc for machine read

Tags: c++, code-generation, doxygen

Is it possible to use doxygen generate a machine readable metadata, like json, I googled, but found nothing.

> ... generate an on-line documentation browser (in HTML) and/or an off-line reference manual (in LaTeX) from a set of documented source files. There is also support for generating output in RTF (MS-Word), PostScript, hyperlinked PDF, compressed HTML, DocBook and Unix man pages.

There must some internal abstract metadata to support doxygen. I want to use the doxygen's metadata so I don't have to parse the source code to get something like methods, args,from doxygen, I also got comments for free.

With these data I can generate glue code for some other languages. So, how can I get these metadata out of doxygen ?

Answer (score 3):

doxygen can also generate XML.

The schema can be found in the source code:

https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/templates/xml/compound.xsd

The xsd is also available in the generated output, in the xml directory.

With an XSLT transformation, you can process the generated XML and extract the data needed.